# Jersey 2 Server Sent + client side Event source not working properly

Tags: javascript, java, jersey-2.0, server-sent-events

I am using jersey 2 to implement server sent . when i do a curl i am getting proper response back with a one second of delay as expected. But when i try to use event source from client side , it waits for all the events to get completed and then onmessage is called. Also it repeatedly making server calls .. below is the server side and client side code i am using. 
Server side jersey code

```
    @GET
@Path("/serverSentCheck")
@Produces(SseFeature.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
@ManagedAsync
public EventOutput serverSentCheck() {
    final EventOutput eventOutput = new EventOutput();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    final OutboundEvent.Builder eventBuilder
                    = new OutboundEvent.Builder();
                   // eventBuilder.name("message-to-client");
                    eventBuilder.data(String.class,
                        "Hello world " + i + "!");
                    final OutboundEvent event = eventBuilder.build();
                    eventOutput.write(event);
                }
            } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Error when writing the event.", e);
            } finally {
                try {
                    eventOutput.close();
                } catch (IOException ioClose) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(
                        "Error when closing the event output.", ioClose);
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
    return eventOutput;
}
```

client side eventsource code

```
var source = new EventSource(" https://localhost:7080/api/v1/service/serverSentCheck");
source.onmessage = function(event) {
    console.log(event.data);
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += event.data + "<br>";
};
```

Curl command thats working properly

```
curl  --insecure -H "Accept:text/event-stream" https://localhost:7080/api/v1/service/serverSentCheck
```

Answer (score 0):

After scratching my head for some time, I was able to find out the problem . Mentioning here so that it may help someone else who encounter the same issue. On my server side GZIP was enabled by default. When I changed to compression per API, and excluded serversent from being compressed, everything works fine.